# Debugging ANTLR4 grammar

Tags: antlr4

I'm a n00b to ANTLR and going big by trying to get an ASN.1 parser running in ANTLR4.  I am presently at the stage where I'm passing in an input file to grun and seeing errors like "line 1:12029 no viable alternative at input ..."

I'm trying to relate this back to some problem with my rules but locating the offending input by character count is a challenge.  Is it normal for an ANTLR parser to see the input as a single line, or am I failing to recognize EOLs because of a rule problem (I'm on an OSX system)?  If it is normal to see the input as one long line, can someone recommend a tool for locating a given character position in a file?

Answer (score 3):

Does your code use only `\r` line endings? ANTLR 4 increments the line count and resets the char position only when a `\n` character is consumed. If you need to handle plain `\r` line endings, you'll need to override `LexerATNSimulator.consume` to perform this check.

Checking for the complete set of line endings is *much* more expensive than checking for `\n` alone, so since `\r` line endings are rare the default implementation uses `\n` for maximum performance.

Comment: Thanks! I am unblocked again.  I should have tried converting line terminators on the input file before asking...